# Burger / Collapsed menu not listing

Tags: html, mobile, twitter-bootstrap-3, hamburger-menu

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
      <!-- MÅ FIKSES, HAMBURGERMENY -->
           <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
               <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button> <!-- Må FIKSES -->
        <a class="navbar-brand top-20 bottom-20 brand-border" href="index.html"><img src="images/afk-logo.png"/></a>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="top-10 left-25">
          <h3 class="fat3 hidden-sm hidden-xs hidden-md">Vurdering for læring</h3>
        </li>
          <li>
            <a class="top-20 bottom-20 left-50" href="artikkelmal.html">For lærere og skoleledere</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="top-20 bottom-20" href="#">For elever og foresatte</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="top-20 bottom-20" href="#">Om rammeverk for vurdering</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="top-5 hidden-sm hidden-xs hidden-md" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search roundy-glyphicon" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

The problem is that the Burger menu in mobile screen is not functioning. All it does is clicking it active, then none of the links appear. Can I use different classes inside a `<li>` for instance? Or is this preventing it from working?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to have classes on nested elements in li tag. Have you tried something like:

```
<span class="top-20 bottom-20"><a href="#">For elever og foresatte</a></span>
```